# What does [:] mean in groovy?

Tags: variables, groovy, definition

While reading some groovy code of another developer I encountered the following definition:

```
def foo=[:]
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

`[:]` is shorthand notation for [creating a Map](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_map_literals).

You can also add keys and values to it:

```
def foo = [bar: 'baz']
```

Comment: I imagine multiple entries are separated by a comma? `[bar: 'baz', qux: 'quux']`

Answer (score 16):

`[:]` creates an empty Map. The colon is there to distinguish it from `[]`, which creates an empty List.

This groovy code:

```
def foo = [:]
```

is roughly equivalent to this java code:

```
Object foo = new java.util.LinkedHashMap();
```

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [the doc](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#Collections-Maps):

> Notice that `[:]` is the empty map expression.

... which is the only `Map` with `size()` returning 0. ) By itself, it's rarely useful, but you can add values into this Map, of course:

```
def emptyMap = [:]
assert emptyMap.size() == 0
emptyMap.foo = 5
assert emptyMap.size() == 1
assert emptyMap.foo == 5
```

Comment: Technically, "is the only `Map` with `size()` returning 0" is untrue. There are lots of possible map instances with size 0, and they definitely don't all have reference equality. They will all be "equal", though (assuming they don't get mutated), which is probably what you meant.