# What is an empty array with a colon in Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins

In Jenkins, I have seen

```
def map = [:]
```

And also this form:

```
def map = []
```

What is the difference between them?

Comment: Jenkins scripting is based on groovy.. First one is map, second is actually list

Comment: Thank you Jayan.

Comment: There is a similar question like this in SO. You can find it here [This groovy code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22865232/10363259)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does \[:\] mean in groovy?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22865107/what-does-mean-in-groovy)